# OpenCV Mat per-element operation: vector-matrix multiplication

Tags: opencv, matrix, matrix-multiplication, mat

**I** is an *mxn* matrix and each element of **I** is a *1x3* vector (**I** is a 3-channel Mat image actually).

**M** is a *3x3* matrix.

**J** is an matrix having the same dimension as **I** and is computed as follows: each element of **J** is the vector-matrix product of the corresponding (i.e. having the same coordinates) element of **I** and **M**.

I.e. if *v1(r1,g1,b1)* is an element of **I** and *v2(r2,g2,b2)* is its corresponding element of **J**, then *v2* = *v1* * **M** (this is a vector-matrix product, not a per-element product).

Question: How to compute **J** efficiently (in terms of speed)?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, the most efficient way to implement such an operation is as follows:

1. Reshape **I** from *mxnx3* to *(m·n)x3*, let's call it **I'**
2. Calculate **J'** = **I'** * **M**
3. Reshape **J'** from *(m·n)x3* to *mxnx3*, this is the **J** we wanted

The idea is to stack each pixel-wise operation **p<sub>i</sub>'**·**M** into one single operation **P'**·**M**, where **P** is the *3x(m·n)* matrix containing each pixel in columns (hence **P'** holds one pixel per row. It's just a convention, really).

Here is a code sample written in c++:

```cpp
//  read some image
cv::Mat I = cv::imread("image.png");               //  rows x cols x 3

//  some matrix M, that modifies each pixel
cv::Mat M = (cv::Mat_<float>(3, 3) << 0,  0,  0, 
                                      0, .5,  0, 
                                      0,  0, .5);  //  3 x 3

//  remember old dimension
uint8_t prevChannels = I.channels;                 
uint32_t prevRows = I.rows;                        

//  reshape I
uint32_t newRows = I.rows * I.cols;                
I = I.reshape(1, newRows);                         //  (rows * cols) x 3

//  compute J
cv::Mat J = I * M;                                 //  (rows * cols) x 3

//  reshape to original dimensions
J = J.reshape(prevChannels, prevRows);             //  rows x cols x 3
```

OpenCV provides an *O(1)* reshaping operation.
Thus performance depends solely on matrix multiplication, which I expect to be as efficient as possible in a computer vision library.

To further enhance performance, you might want to take a look at matrix multiplication using the [ocl](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ocl/doc/operations_on_matrices.html#ocl-gemm) and [gpu](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/operations_on_matrices.html#gpu-gemm) modules.